# Usage of the Dr title

Tags: usage, académique, université

> La Cour de cassation a rappelé avec fermeté en 2009 que le titre de docteur pouvait être porté par les titulaires d'un doctorat de troisième cycle universitaire et que la contestation de ce fait pouvait valoir diffamation. En outre l'article 78 de la loi du 22 juillet 2013 précise que : « les titulaires d'un doctorat peuvent faire usage du titre de docteur, en mentionnant la spécialité, dans tout emploi et toute circonstance professionnelle qui le justifient ».
>
> Une erreur fréquente consiste à considérer que l'usage du titre de docteur est réservé aux médecins. Cette confusion provient d'une erreur de lecture d'une ancienne législation (modifiée en 2005), qui interdisait l'usage du titre de docteur aux non-médecins cherchant à exercer une activité médicale.
>
> Référence : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docteur_(titre)#France

Cet usage du titre de D<sup>r</sup> est-il répandu en France ou son emploi se limite-t-il à l'enseignement supérieur ?
Exemple : John Dupont, D<sup>r</sup> en mécanique. Certains m'ont suggéré de ne pas l'utiliser (dans les e-mails professionnels ou les notes de cours par exemple). Ils me disent qu'il vaut mieux utiliser des titres comme professeur(e), maître(sse) de conférences, chargé(e) d'enseignement, etc., selon le cas. Ont-ils raison ?

Comment: Cf. [Du bon usage du Titre de « Docteur »](https://www.snsh.info/flashinfo/Mememto_SNSH_Usage_Titre_Docteur.pdf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Légalement, en France, tu as le droit de dire que tu es « Dimitris Dupont, Docteur en mécanique », si tu as le diplôme de doctorat du troisième cycle (équivalent du Ph.D. anglo-saxon) dans la discipline en question. C'est ce que dit [la loi citée](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000027735009&categorieLien=id#JORFARTI000027735139).

Mais cet usage n'est absolument pas dans les mœurs. En France, il n'y a que les professions médicales qui utilisent *docteur* comme titre. Quand on va voir son médecin, il est courant de lui dire « Bonjour, docteur. ». Si le médecin se présente, il est fréquent qu'il dise « je suis le docteur Duval ». Par contre, quelqu'un qui a un diplôme de doctorat ne se présente pas en disant « je suis le docteur Dupont », mais « je suis monsieur Dupont ». Il peut dire « je suis Dimitris Dupont, docteur en mécanique » s'il veut mentionner son diplôme, mais ce n'est pas courant en dehors d'un CV.

Si Dimitris Dupont a un doctorat de mécanique et donne un cours de mathématiques dans une université, la façon normale de se présenter est « je suis Dimitris Dupont, votre professeur de mathématiques » ou « je suis monsieur Dupont, votre professeur de mathématiques ». Hors du contexte d'une classe, un universitaire se présente souvent par son métier, et non son titre. Le métier « normal » d'un titulaire d'un doctorat qui enseigne est *maître de conférence*, et si c'est le poste qu'occupe Dimitris Dupont, il peut naturellement signer ses courriels « Dimitris Dupont, maître de conférences en physique à la faculté de Paris-Belleville ». C'est le rôle ou le métier qu'on utilise, pas le titre.

Par exemple tout à fait typique, voici comment sont présentées deux tribunes dans le *Monde*, l'une cosignée par un médecin et l'autre par un titulaire d'un doctorat du troisième cycle. (J'ai choisi les premières tribunes venues, sans lien avec l'opinion que je peux en avoir.)

> [Arnaud Pautet, docteur en histoire contemporaine et professeur en classe préparatoire, s’inquiète de la progressive « disparition » des épreuves de dissertation.](https://www.lemonde.fr/education/article/2020/03/10/doit-on-s-inquieter-de-la-mort-annoncee-de-la-dissertation_6032432_1473685.html)
>
> [...]
>
> Arnaud Pautet (Docteur en histoire contemporaine, professeur en classe préparatoire)

Arnaud Pautet a le diplôme de docteur, le métier et le poste de professeur (enseignant dans l'enseignement supérieur), et ne fait pas œuvre d'un titre.

> [[...] estiment dans une tribune au « Monde » le professeur Emmanuel Barranger et le docteur Jérôme Barrière, oncologues](https://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2020/05/20/la-requisition-de-produits-d-anesthesie-n-est-pas-justifiee-et-gene-la-reprise-generale-des-soins_6040291_3232.html)
>
> [...]
>
> Emmanuel Barranger (Chirurgien oncologue, directeur général du centre de lutte contre le cancer Antoine-Lacassagne (Fédération Unicancer), Nice.) et Jérôme Barrière (Médecin oncologue, président de la commission médicale d’établissement, polyclinique Saint-Jean, Cagnes-sur-Mer.)

Jérôme Barrière fait œuvre du titre de docteur, ne mentionne pas ses diplômes, et mentionne sa profession de médecin ainsi que son poste de président d'une commission médicale. Emmanuel fait œuvre du titre de professeur (c'est le titre correspondant à la profession de chirurgien), mentionne sa profession de chirurgien ainsi que son poste de directeur général d'un établissement médical.