# Y a-t-il une abréviation pour le titre d'"académicien.ne"?

Tags: abréviations, titres

Le titre de civilité docteur.e (resp. monseigneur) a pour abréviation Dr (resp. Mgr).
Y a-t-il quelque chose de similaire pour « académicien.ne » ?

Comment: Peux-tu éclaircir ta question ? Resp. → usuellement *responsable*, mais que veux-tu dire ici ?  peut-être *respectable* , ce qui serait possible mais pas du tout usuel en français hexagonal, l'équivalent de l'anglais "hon." ? Monseigneur n'est plus guère employé que pour les évêques (abréviation Mgr).  En France, on n'utilise le titre de docteur que pour les docteurs en médecine (c'est une question d'usage, voir cette [excellente explication](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/42027/358)).

Comment: Je ne crois pas qu'en France académicien soit un titre ([apparemment ça l'est en Finlande](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9micien_(Finlande))), ça indique juste une appartenance. En France « Pour s’adresser à un académicien, il convient d’user du titre qui lui revient dans la vie civile... » ([Lire sur le site de l'Académie Française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/pierre-alban-ch-france))

Comment: @None personnellement j'ai interprété `resp.` comme l'abréviation de `respectivement`, mais il faudrait confirmation

Comment: @AloisChristen Resp. dans un contexte mathématiques en effet c'est *respectivement*, mais dans ce contexte c'est pas clair pour moi.  Je pense que le titre se suffit à lui même pour comprendre ce que le PO demande, ce sont les explications qui suivent qui sont plutôt embrouillées. La demande d'éclaircissement a été faite.

Comment: Utiliser l'écriture inclusive pour désigner les membres de l'Académie française est assez savoureux.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne suis pas sûr d'avoir compris la question, je me contente donc de répondre au titre, à savoir, s'il y a une abréviation pour le titre d'académicien.

Selon ce que je sais *académicien/académicienne* n'est pas un titre, dire que untel ou unetelle est académicien ou académicienne indique qu'il/elle est membre d'une académie<sup>1</sup>. L'abréviation d'Académie recommandée par le *Lexique des règles typographiques en usage à l'Imprimerie nationale* l'abréviation d'Académie est Acad. mais il n'y a pas d'abréviation usuelle pour académicien.

En ce qui concerne les membres de l'Académie française, on peut lire [sur le site de l'Académie](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/pierre-alban-ch-france) :

> Pour s’adresser à un académicien, il convient d’user du titre qui lui revient dans la vie civile. Par exemple, on s’adressera à un ministre, ou ancien ministre, par la formule « Monsieur le Ministre », à un professeur par « Monsieur le Professeur », à un ecclésiastique par son titre (« Mon Père », « Mon Révérend Père », « Monsieur le Cardinal », etc.). Pour s’adresser au Secrétaire perpétuel de l’Académie, on utilisera la formule « Monsieur ou Madame le Secrétaire perpétuel ». Si aucun titre particulier n’est attaché à la personne de l’académicien, on dira simplement « Monsieur » ou « Madame ». La formule d’adresse « Maître » peut être employée mais elle reste peu fréquente. En revanche, on ne dira jamais « Monsieur l’académicien ».
> Sur l’enveloppe d’une lettre, on écrira également le titre de l’académicien ou « Monsieur X, de l’Académie… ».

Donc le titre d'un membre de l'Académie française est tout simplement le titre qu'il a dans la vie civile. Et je pense qu'il en est de même avec les membres des autres académies ([Académie des beaux-arts](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_des_beaux-arts_(France)), [Académie des sciences](https://www.academie-sciences.fr/fr/), etc.) Si le membre d'une académie est médecin, on pourra donc utiliser le titre de docteur (Dr), le titre de docteur n'étant utilisé en France que pour les docteurs en médecine<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>Selon Wikipedia [académicien](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9micien) serait un titre honorifique en Finlande.</sub> 
<sub><sup>2</sup> Ce n'est pas l'usage en France d'utiliser le titre de docteur quand on a un doctorat autre qu'un doctorat en médecine, voir [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/42027/358) sur ce site.</sub>